# Adding a background image in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, background, windows-store-apps

Recently I started making a Windows Store App in XAML and in C#. Unfortunately I failed with adding a background png image stored in '/Assets'. Looked everywhere for any glues but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Here is my code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BoggleV01.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BoggleV01"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Margin="160,100" Width="1040">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Background.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />                                            
        </Grid.Background>

        <StackPanel x:Name="levelsStackPanel"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="568" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="playersStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="568" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="260,0,0,0"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="statisticsStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="568" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="520,0,0,0"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="settingsStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="568" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="780,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below mentioned code

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/Applicationname;component/Assets/Background.png"
            Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Comment: Dhaval, Somehow this did not solve my problem, I also tried `<ImageBrush ImageSource="/BoggleV01;component/Assets/Background.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />` just in case I needed to replace Applicationname with my namespace.

Comment: have you replace your application name in applicationname string?

Comment: Application name is the namespace am I right? In that case yeah I have done that.